# restrict to download the pdf files

Tags: php, html, pdf, download

I am working on online pdf library project. In this I have a feature that any user can read the file.But if the file is readable than it is sure that i can be downloaded.
Is there any way so that we can block user to download that file.?
If he want to download the file than he have to signup..Can php pdf library can help us?

Comment: If you allow a user to view a PDF file on your site, then there's nothing preventing the user from taking screen captures and assembling PDFs of their own.

Comment: By allowing them to view it, you are already letting them download it, perhaps give them an alternative file with fewer pages instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. As Jamie said, reading is downloading. When a user is reading a file, browser is downloading that file to temp. So even if you disable the download button, the user can click "File -> Save As" or copy that file from temp folder.

A solution is to give only a sample (first few pages, for example) to the public, and to access the full, they need to signup. I have no better solution in mind that to manually keep 2 files in the server - full and abstract.

Answer (score 0):

use js/jquery, when download button hit, trigger signup page and upon completion you can allow download. similar to docstoc.com